# How best to structure a definition list with accessibility in mind

Tags: html, css

I have a `dl` that I've coded like so:

```
<dl>
  <dt>term 1</dt>
    <dd>definition 1</dd>
  <dt>term 2</dt>
    <dd>definition 2</dd>
  <dt>term 3</dt>
    <dd>definition 3</dd>
</dl>
```

I'm finding it hard to apply the right css for the layout that i want ie. each term and definition in a column. structuring the html in the following way would solve my problem but I am wondering, is this ok? (from an accessibility point of view).

```
<dl>
    <dt>term 1</dt>
    <dd>definition 1</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>term 2</dt>
    <dd>definition 2</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>term 3</dt>
    <dd>definition 3</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Now really sure how it is you want to style it or why it's causing an issue, but perhaps you can make use of a `<span>` somewhere? I find often if I can't do what I want in CSS the solution is always more boxes. Try: `<dl><span><dt>...</dt><dd>...</dd></span><span>...</span></dl>`, keeping them all in the same `<dl>` but using multiple `<span>`s to separate each term. Otherwise, maybe you could solve your problem applying CSS differently to `dl dt` and `dl dd`?

Answer (score 1):

Putting each term in its own list makes it impossible to determine programmatically that the three terms are actually related to each other (in that they're part of the same bit of content on your site). Deviating from standards is certainly necessary from time to time, but you've said nothing that demonstrates that it's necessary here.

If your original underlying problem is "I can't get this list styled the way I want," perhaps a better question for Stack Overflow is: "How can I style this list to look like **__**."

Comment: It would make sense to keep the list as one because the terms are related to each other.

Comment: Exactly. You don't really have three different lists; you have one list with three different terms. Any other markup is incorrect. Again, that's not to say incorrect markup can absolutely **never** be used; but it is incorrect.

Comment: It would make sense to keep the list as one because the terms are related to each other. so i need to get help with the css.... I'll have to post it as another question as it seems i can't add code here.... cheers guys

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not fully semantic (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp) but nobody wants to worry ^^
You can say you have many lists of one definition !

Comment: It's not semantically correct as MatTheCat said, but I won't tell anyone.